# Java sockets: Program stops at socket.getInputStream() w/o error?

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

```
InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
Socket link = new Socket(host, Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
System.out.println("before input stream");
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(link.getInputStream());
System.out.println("before output stream");
ObjectInputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(link.getOutputStream());
```

"before input stream" is the last lifesign on cmd-line. There is no Exception thrown. Why is this happening? I don't understand...

args[0] is 5000.
//edit: flush doesn't help.

Comment: have you run it from the debugger?  perhaps that'll break into the code and give you an idea of whats going on.

Comment: @Brian It connects automatically in the constructor.

Comment: @user Last line in your code doesn't compile. `..Input.. out = new ..Output..`

Comment: Obviously my memory failed me. I stand corrected :)

Comment: Also: ObjectInputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(link.getOutputStream());

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is because the `ObjectInputStream(InputStream in)`-constructor is a blocking-call if the inputStream is empty.

[Quote](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#ObjectInputStream(java.io.InputStream)):

> Creates an ObjectInputStream that reads from the specified InputStream. A serialization stream header is read from the stream and verified. This constructor **will block** until the corresponding ObjectOutputStream has written and flushed the header.

Comment: so if i make the outputstream on the client and on the server side first, that should work? interessting.... i will give it a try. thanks.

Comment: well yes. if I exchange the creation of the streams it works. like written below, the `ObjectInputStream out`-thing is just a typo. thanks@all!

Comment: Very basic thing but very necessary to know. Thanks man you saved my days

Answer (score 0):

Possibly,

```
link.getInputStream();
```

could be returning null, though that should return an error by looking at the class files.
Another thing I noticed was, you declare:

```
ObjectInputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(link.getOutputStream());
```

From this, you are stating a ObjectInputStream as a ObjectOutputStream without a cast (Would not be appropriate here anyways)

you should try:

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(link.getOutputStream());
```

This should work, as the script may queue the System.out, but notice the error before it can be initialized.

Tell me if this works :D