# Java thread stuck with notify call

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

i'm stuck with this code, and i think that i'm missing something really important.
when the thread is running i can add message to the vector 
but when it calls notify it seems that the `getNextMessageFromQueue()` keep to stay on the wait.

Am i locking the *messages* vars?

Thanks for your help.

My dispatcher class which send all messages to my clients :

```
private Vector<Message> messages = new Vector<Message>(); 

public synchronized void addMessage(Message message) {
    messages.add(message);
    notify(); 
}

private synchronized Message getNextMessageFromQueue() throws InterruptedException { 
    while (messages.size() < 1) {
        wait(); 
    }

    Message message = (Message) messages.get(0); 
    messages.removeElementAt(0);

    return message; 
}

private void sendMessageToAllClients(Message message) {     
    for (int i=0; i < clients.size(); i++) { 
        Client client = (Client) clients.get(i); 
        client.sendMessage(message); 
    } 
}

public void run() { 
    try { 
        while (true) { 
            Message message = getNextMessageFromQueue(); 
            sendMessageToAllClients(message); 
        } 
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Here the client class :

```
private Socket socket;

private ObjectOutputStream out;
private ObjectInputStream in;

public Client(Socket s) throws IOException {
    socket = s;

    out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
}

public Socket getSocket() {
    return socket;
}

public void sendMessage(Message message) { 
    try {
        out.writeObject(message);
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
}
```

Here is the main call of `addMessage` :

```
Message message = new Message();
message.setMessage("Welcome to " + client.getSocket().getLocalAddress() + ":" + client.getSocket().getPort());

dispatcher.addMessage(message);
```

Comment: Is there any other call to wait() somewhere else? You're not showing us the complete code. Might the call to `client.sendMessage()` block? Why is sendMessageToAllClients() synchronized? It doesn't use the vector.

Comment: @user1952589 - Then please post that code also.

Comment: Why don't use [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) take()/put()? (Vector is generic, Queue may be more appropriate)

Comment: I remember there's a question and answer which states that we should avoid `synchronized` methods and gave an example but *I just can't find it now*

Comment: can you println something to console immediately after `wait` line in order to see whether thread gets notified?

Comment: It might be helpful if you came up with a simple complete example that demonstrated the problem and that we could experiment with.

Comment: @Alvin Wong, I think it is more generally about synchronizing around `this` (which is what method-level synchronization does) because clients may wish to synchronize against your object and thus unwillingly interfere with your own locking.

Comment: Can you try notifyAll() instead of notify().

Comment: @user1952589 Did you make debug?

Comment: @user1952589 Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a mistake in line `in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());`
Remove it, if it is not necessary or rebuild in other way. Read this [Java sockets: Program stops at socket.getInputStream() w/o error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186135/java-sockets-program-stops-at-socket-getinputstream-w-o-error)

To understand if your inputData is empty use - socket.getInputStream().available(), it returns size of input bytes.